# FQL equilant for page feed

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Hi
I am looking for the FQL equlant for https://graph.facebook.com/coca-cola/feed

The above Graph API call will return lot of data which I don't need.. I am looking for the FQL equilant to return only the id, from_id, from_name, message and created_time.

Please help

Best Regards...

Comment: Just an FYI, there are a lot of posts to the feed which do not their relevant content in the "message" field

Answer (score 1):

Here's the table you should query http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/.

However, it might be easier to request `https://graph.facebook.com/coca-cola/feed?fields=id,from_id,from_name,message,created_time`. Though, it returns an error - `from_id` and `from_name` don't exist, thus try `https://graph.facebook.com/coca-cola/feed?fields=id,message,created_time`.

Hope it helps.